# Security group configuration for fargate task accesing ec2 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-fargate

I have quite wierd problem with an AWS setup which I thought would be starightforward.

I have a fargate Task which is run from a lambda function.
The awsvpc config for this fargate task is as follows:

```
'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                'subnets': [
                    'subnet-toing',
                    'subnet-xxxx',
                    'subnet-yyyy'
                ],
                'securityGroups': [
                    'sg-toing'
                ],
                'assignPublicIp': 'ENABLED'
            }
```

The fargate task runs a docker image that connects to a EC2 instance (with it's IP mapped to db.toing.kp) which runs a db on, lets say port *n*. My ec2 instance's security group is configured to allow requests from `sg-toing` on port *n*. The ec2 instance runs on the `subnet-toing` subnet. All the subnets are from the same VPC.

Just as extra info: in my EC2 instance, the hosts file has a line to resolve requests on its subnet. Let's say the instance local ip is 172.x.y.z. There is a line:

```
172.x.y.z. db.toing.kp
```

This is basically for replication tasks, so the DB data won't go all over the internet to connect to the replicas.

So the problem is that when I try to run the fargate task it cannot connect to the EC2 instance, the connection times out.

However, if I remove the firewall rule for connections from the `sg-toing` security group and allow all, everything works as expected. Can someone please explain why the EC2 instance would not accept connections from the fargate task with this config? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sg-toing` is configured to accepts requests from port `n`. But you host entry sends requests to `172.x.y.z` , not `172.x.y.z:n`

If you can connect to your db, using the `ip:port`, without the host entry, there won't be an issue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: we can't define ports in the host file. Actually the problem was with the the hosts file, after I removed the entries and directly accessed via the local subnet IPs, it was okay. I don't understand how exactly how a server-local hosts file woulds affect a security group, but neither do AWS support, apparently :)

Comment: yes, we cant define ports in the host file. In my answer, I have said: "If you can connect to your db, using the ip:port, without the host entry". Isn't that what you did to resolve the issue?

Comment: Basically, yes! But Iam quite sure that the EC2 instance was rejecting even with the local IP, because I recreated this issue for an AWS agent. However, when I removed the hosts file, it was fine, the problem is that the hosts file has nothing to do with incoming requests AFAIK. So in short, yes, I found a solution, but not what I wanted because I had to change the whole replicaset config. :( Maybe I did something stupid somewhere, I don't know, but in either case, thanks for your help!
PS: on your answer, I can't agree on the first 2 sentences though.